# Protractor - Tests execution stops abruptly when assertion is failed

Tags: protractor, chai, e2e-testing, cucumberjs

**Cucumber step definition**

```
Then(/^Submit Button is disabled$/, function (done) {
    element(by.buttonText('Search')).isEnabled().then(function (result) {

        expect(result).to.equal(false);
        done();
    });
})
```

**Console error:**

> [12:17:13] E/launcher - expected false to equal true
>   [12:17:13] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected false to equal true
>       at D:\Mercurial\PromotionFinder\PromotionFinder\PromotionFinder.Web\features\steps\cucumber.js:178:31
>       at elementArrayFinder_.then (C:\Users\abhishes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\element.ts:840:22)
>       at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\abhishes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1366:14)
>       at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\abhishes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
>       at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\abhishes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
>       at asyncRun (C:\Users\abhishes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2813:27)
>       at C:\Users\abhishes\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>   [12:17:13] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199

**Protractor configuration**

```
exports.config = {
  // seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:9001/',
  resultJsonOutputFile: "./e2e_report/report.json",
  getPageTimeout: 60000,
  allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
  framework: 'custom',
  // path relative to the current config file
  frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--start-maximized'
      ]
    }
  },
  // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
  specs: [
    './features/*.feature'
  ],
  baseURL: 'https://angularjs.org/',
  cucumberOpts: {
    require: ["./features/globals.js", './features/steps/*.js'],
    tags: [],
    format: 'pretty',
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true,
    "compiler": [] //,
    //format:"json:./e2e_report/report.json"
  }
};
```

whenever assertion is failed test execution stop abruptly and no test report is generated.

I am using 
**Protractor version - 5, cucumberjs version 2.0.0 and chai & chai-as-promised for assertion**

I want information like below:

1 scenario (1 failed)
5 steps (1 failed, 3 skipped, 1 passed)

and result.json to be created so that i can see results in teamcity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't yet worked with CucumberJS 2.0.0 because it is a RC version and I saw some troubles with it on the internet. 2.1.0 is a stable version, so maybe that can solve the problem.

When I look at your code I think this should do the trick.

```js
// With callbacks
Then(/^Submit Button is disabled$/, function(done) {
  var searchButton = element(by.buttonText('Search'));
  return expect(searchButton.isEnabled()).to.eventually.equal(false).and.notify(done);
});

// With Promises
Then(/^Submit Button is disabled$/, function() {
  var searchButton = element(by.buttonText('Search'));
  return expect(searchButton.isEnabled()).to.eventually.equal(false);
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the exceptions.
There are two ways to do it.
Catching the exception at the return...

```
Then(/^Submit Button is disabled$/, function (done) {
    element(by.buttonText('Search')).isEnabled().then(function (result) {

        expect(result).to.equal(false);
        done();
    }).catch(function(err){
            return;
    });
});
```

Other is by adding callback as a parameter in the function definition.

```
Then(/^Submit Button is disabled$/, function (done, callback) {
    element(by.buttonText('Search')).isEnabled().then(function (result) {

        expect(result).to.equal(false);
        done();
    }).catch(function(reason) {
            callback(reason);
    });
});
```